# How can I rewrite this to not have the Type mismatch error?

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style

How do I rewrite this code to not have the Type Mismatch error on return Math.abs(i);

```
public static int[] countDigits(Scanner input) {
            int[] count = new int[10];
            int i = input.nextInt();
            while (Math.abs(i) >= 10 ) {
                i = i / 10;
            }
            return Math.abs(i);
```

This is the segment of code in particular that I need help with.It Reads integers from input, computing an array of counts for the occurrences of each leading digit (0-9).

Comment: I don't know what this function is supposed to do. But why does it have return type `int[]`? Besides, I think you want `input.nextInt()` inside the loop as well.

Comment: You are trying to return an int when the return type is int[].

Answer (score 1):

Change your return type from `int[]` to `int`... because [Math.abs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29) returns one Integer. Not an array of Integers. Like this

```
public static int countDigits(Scanner input)
```